# Translating pages, only the last version remains

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am setting up my first Drupal site, with Drupal 7, which is multilingual; I thought after surprisingly much work I had set it up correctly.
I can choose a language for each page, and translate pages, but when I translate a page, all translations of that page will have the same text: the last one I entered. So the text of the other language versions is overwritten by the last edited one. Did I do anything wrong? Is there a bug?

You may have a look [here](http://einfalt.ch.nu-media-comm.ch/drupal/de/node/7).

The login credentials, if you want to test it are: test, test.

Comment: Please provide some more details.  What modules are you using to make it multilingual?  (locale, i18n, etc.)

Comment: Oh, that's a hard one. I installed everything that had sth. "language" in it ... checking ... there is:

- Content translation
- Locale
- Translation overview
- Localization update
- MULTILINGUAL - INTERNATIONALIZATION (with 15 submodules)

(thanks, @espero, for the editing. how do you get newlines to stay in a message?)

Comment: ok, figured out the newline thing -> help. But cannot edit my previous comment anymore ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the 'synchronize translations' submodule of i18n was enabled.
I took the privilege of disabling it on your test site. 
I know multilanguage is a tricky part in D7 but you should start with the basics of multilanguage by enabling locale, content translation, Internationalization, block languages, multilingual content and string translation. Just to get a feeling of what you're doing.
Later on you can activate some other submodules of the i18n module but in my opinion it is never a good idea to activate all at once.
 Activating to many modules at once can result in losing control of your installation like you're having right now.

Comment: Thank you! 6 modules, just for the basics??? OMG. I had heard, and meanwhile got a feeling, too, that Drupal was a module orgy ... Sorry, I'm used to simple stuff, such as Joomla and Magento, will take a while to get used to this.

Comment: The bare basics are just locale and content translation, but it's really limited. Drupal can look sometimes like a module orgy (lol) but once you get to know it it's quite fun to play with. Good luck!